# Vuetify's v-autocomplete component resets the v-model value to null when cleared

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js, v-autocomplete

In the code below I am using a v-autocomplete component
and a variable `select` where the selected value is stored.
The `watch` logs the value and type of `select`.
The problem I'm facing is that when the text typed in the v-autocomplete is cleared, `select` defaults to null instead of an empty string.
Is there any way to revert `select` to an empty string instead of a null object?

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-card>
      <v-container fluid>
        <v-row
          align="center"
        >
          <v-col cols="12">
            <v-autocomplete
              v-model="select"
              :items="items"
              dense
              filled
              label="Filled"
              clearable
            ></v-autocomplete>
          </v-col>
        </v-row>
      </v-container>
    </v-card>
  </v-app>
</div>

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data: () => ({
    items: ['foo', 'bar', 'fizz', 'buzz'],
    select: "",
  }),
  watch:{
    value:function(value){
      console.log(this.select) // select value
      console.log(typeof(this.value)); // select variable type
    }
  }
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`v-model='select'` is a shorthand for `:value="select"` and `@input="select = $event"`. Thus, if you want to customize the behaviour of emitted `@input` event, you can write it in expanded form.

In below snippet, when the input value changes, you assign it to `select` if it is not null, or assign an empty string otherwise.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data: () => ({
    items: ['foo', 'bar', 'fizz', 'buzz'],
    select: "",
  }),
  watch:{
    select:function(value){
      console.log(value) // select value
      console.log(typeof(value)); // select variable type
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@4.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-card>
      <v-container fluid>
        <v-row
          align="center"
        >
          <v-col cols="12">
            <v-autocomplete
              :value="select"
              @input="select = $event || ''"
              :items="items"
              dense
              filled
              label="Filled"
              clearable
            ></v-autocomplete>
          </v-col>
        </v-row>
      </v-container>
    </v-card>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Comment: This worked like a charm. Thanks a lot. I had been looking for a solution to this for a long time.